# Login with token-based API?

Tags: django, api, authentication, django-rest-framework, http-token-authentication

I'm building a Django web app with an api that uses token-based authentication, rather than session-based. The api is consumed both by the frontend of the web app and by a separate mobile app. I'm having a tough time figuring out how to do login. My first thought was to just do what I'm planning to do in the mobile app: the login form just POSTs to the endpoint that creates and sends back an access token, then the access token is saved in the browser/app storage to be sent along with future requests. This seems to make sense in the context of a mobile app, but with a browser it seems kind of strange. One problem with this approach is that the internal pages will still be visible even after logging out. A user could logout, then hit the back button, and just browse around the site. Even though all of the api calls will fail, they static content will still be served up.

It seems to me that the difference is that in a mobile app, authentication is only needed for api calls, as the static content is already on the device and doesn't need to be fetched. In a web app, however, the static content needs to be served up, and it probably shouldn't be if the user is not logged in.

Is it uncommon to use only token-based authentication? Will I need to use session-based authentication for static content, along with using token-based authentication for the api?

How is this normally done?

**EDIT**: I'm using django-rest-framework, so a simple way to handle this with that would also be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hook up your JS API calls such that authentication failures will redirect the current page back to the login page.

```
$http({url: "/api/v1/thing"})
    .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        // Do something
    })
    .failure(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        if (status == 403) {
             window.location.href = "/login/?next="+window.location.href
        }
    })
```

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks! Do you know if this is standard practice?

Comment: I don't know if this is standard practice. We write out apps using Angular, and the root page for the app is protected by session based auth. once on the page, token auth is used to communicate with the API. if the user gets logged out for any reason, we have an HTTP interceptor installed which catches 403 and 401 and takes the appropriate action (redirect to login or display permission denied message).